# PostgreSQL : Accessing tables owned by another user

Tags: postgresql, roles, owner

As a Superuser, I have created two roles in Postgres on the same schema:

1. `read_only_with_create_view`
2. `read_write`

Then I created two users from each role:

1. `read_only_with_create_view_user`
2. `read_write`

Now any new views created by `read_only_with_create_view_user` cannot be accessed by `read_write_user` as the owner for views is different (`read_only_with_create_view_user`).

So what is the way to access all new views by `read_write_user`?

I want everything created by one user to be accessible to another user.

Steps I followed:

```
CREATE ROLE read_only_role WITH
NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION VALID UNTIL 'infinity';

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb to read_only_role;
GRANT USAGE,CREATE ON SCHEMA myschema TO read_only_role;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myschema TO read_only_role;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA myschema TO read_only_role;

CREATE USER read_only_with_create_view_user
WITH PASSWORD '*****'
in ROLE read_only_role;

-- Now created new views using this role. That means read_only_with_create_view_user is owner of those views.

-- Creating new read-write role. 

CREATE ROLE rw_role WITH
NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION VALID UNTIL 'infinity' IN ROLE read_only_role;

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb to rw_role;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA myschema TO crn_rw_role_qa;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myschema TO rw_role;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA myschema TO rw_role;

CREATE USER read_write_user
WITH PASSWORD '*****'
in role rw_role;
```

After login with `read_write_user`, when I try to access new views created by `read_only_with_create_view_user`, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation view_name
********** Error **********

ERROR: permission denied for relation view_name
SQL state: 42501
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a role as a member of another role:

```
GRANT read_only_with_create_view_user TO read_write_user;
```

More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html).

---

**EDIT**

It will never work as you expect. See your current user schema:

[image]

Role `read_write_user` will cannot access objects owned by `read_only_with_create_view_user` simply because both don't have any relationship. To make this works as you expect you can reassign objects ownership to an "upper" level role, in this case: `read_only_role` (because everybody is a member of this role). But be warned that it will **no longer be** a read-only role.

You can do one of the following:

```
--Connected as read_only_with_create_view_user
CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT 1;

--Assign ownership to top-level role
ALTER VIEW my_view OWNER TO read_only_role;
```

Or you may prefer this approach:

```
--Connected as read_only_with_create_view_user
--Change current user to read_only_role
SET role = read_only_role;

--Create a view...
CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT 1;

--Turn back to read_only_with_create_view_user
RESET role;
```

If you prefer to do all at once you can reassign ownership of objects owned by `read_only_with_create_view_user` to your top-level role in just one command:

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY read_only_with_create_view_user TO read_only_role;
```

Finally, if you don't want to break your read-only rule you can also, of course, give permission directly to the object.

```
-- As read_only_with_create_view_user, execute the following:
CREATE VIEW my_view_2 AS SELECT 1;
GRANT SELECT ON my_view_2 TO read_write_user
```

Comment: I have already tried that way while creating role with syntax " create role .... in role ...." but still new views created by read_only_with_create_view_user can not be accessed by read_write_user. It says ERROR:  permission denied for relation view_name
********** Error **********

ERROR: permission denied for relation view_name
SQL state: 42501

Comment: You must show your attempts. Update your question with the commands that you issued.

Comment: Also, check if your roles has `INHERIT` attribute.

Comment: I have updated original question with exact role creation and user creation steps

Comment: Thanks Michel for your detailed explanation

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. If you reasign ownership to "read_only_role", than, that so called "read-only" role can do whatever it wants with the object, even drop it. So it is no longer "read-only" role. So how to accomplish "read-only" access to an object owned by another role/user?